Relationship between sensor timestamps and UTC time using the showcase app or python script
I'm using the Movesense MD sensor for clinical research to collect IMU data. When recording data through the Movesense Medical application, the timestamps are relative, representing an accumulated value in milliseconds from a timestamp (since sensor reset).
Under "Sensor Info" in the movensense showcase app there's a "Set Time" value, but it doesn't seem like the relative timestamp is calculated from that value.

I've also written a Python script to connect directly to the Movesense sensor, and while I successfully retrieved the relative timestamps and data, I couldn't access the base timestamp.
Here are my questions:
Is there a way to determine the relationship between the sensor timestamps and the UTC time using the showcase app or through python script? Is my approach using Python the correct way to get this information (using the Sample GATT SensorData firmware) , or is there another method I should try?
WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "34800001-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0"
NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "34800002-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0"


class DataView:
    def __init__(self, array, bytes_per_element=1):
        self.array = array
        self.bytes_per_element = bytes_per_element

    def __get_binary(self, start_index, byte_count, signed=False):
        integers = [self.array[start_index + x] for x in range(byte_count)]
        _bytes = [
            integer.to_bytes(
                self.bytes_per_element, byteorder="little", signed=signed
            )
            for integer in integers
        ]
        return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, _bytes)

    def get_uint_32(self, start_index):
        return struct.unpack("<I", self.__get_binary(start_index, 4))[0]

    def get_int_64(self, start_index):
        return struct.unpack("<q", self.__get_binary(start_index, 8))[0]


async def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Handle notifications for /Time/Detailed."""
    d = DataView(data)
    try:
        # Parse UTC Time (int64) and Relative Time (uint32)
        utc_time = d.get_int_64(0)
        relative_time = d.get_uint_32(8)
        print(f"Notification Received: UTC Time={utc_time}, Relative Time={relative_time}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in notification handler: {e}")


async def run_ble_client(end_of_serial, queue):
    devices = await discover()
    address = None

    for d in devices:
        if d.name and d.name.endswith(end_of_serial):
            print(f"Device found: {d.name}")
            address = d.address
            break

    if not address:
        print("Device not found!")
        await queue.put(None)
        return

    disconnected_event = asyncio.Event()

    def raise_graceful_exit(*args):
        disconnected_event.set()

    def disconnect_callback(client):
        print("Disconnected from device!")
        disconnected_event.set()

    async with BleakClient(address, disconnected_callback=disconnect_callback) as client:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, raise_graceful_exit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, raise_graceful_exit)

        if not client.is_connected:
            print("Failed to connect to the device!")
            await queue.put(None)
            return

        print("Connected to the device. Subscribing to /Time/Detailed...")
        subscription_command = bytearray([1, 200]) + bytearray("/Time/Detailed", "utf-8")
        await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, subscription_command, response=True)
        await client.start_notify(NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)

        print("Subscribed to /Time/Detailed. Waiting for notifications...")
        await disconnected_event.wait()

        if client.is_connected:
            print("Unsubscribing and stopping notifications...")
            unsubscribe_command = bytearray([2, 200])
            await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, unsubscribe_command, response=True)
            await client.stop_notify(NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)

        await queue.put(None)
        print("Disconnected cleanly.")


async def run_queue_consumer(queue):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        print(data)


async def main(end_of_serial):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    client_task = run_ble_client(end_of_serial, queue)
    consumer_task = run_queue_consumer(queue)
    await asyncio.gather(client_task, consumer_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python script.py <end_of_sensor_serial>")
        sys.exit(1)

    end_of_serial = sys.argv[1]
    asyncio.run(main(end_of_serial))

thanks!

? -> https://www.movesense.com/news/2024/10/python-script-for-collecting-real-time-ecg-and-imu-data/

I have used that example indeed, but that is just the relative timestamp. not /time/detailed
